# Is simulating 3D brownian motion in axially symmetrical 2D sensible?

Tags: simulations, brownian-motion

I'm writing a Monte Carlo particle trajectory simulation program. There are fluid forces like the Stokes drag force involved, as well as Brownian motion. For runtime reasons, the program should be able to run 3D simulations in a projected 2D space, as long as they are axisymmetric. I have the following problem:

- When disregarding Brownian motion, I can get an axisymmetrical 3D and 2D simulation of the same problem to agree wrt. the final position distribution.
- When including Brownian motion, this is not the case: I have not been able to produce a single computational model that can make both simulations agree (see the figures below).

[image: disagreement between 2D and 3D simulations when simulating Brownian motion]

I can not shake the feeling that simulating the Brownian motion of particles in 3D space in 2D does, on some fundamental level, not make sense. I found [a paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/NEMS.2007.352204) that defines such a model (to me it seems it is simply a long derivation of a constant factor) and claims good agreement in 2D and 3D, but there are no external forces involved there, which I assume is a central reason for this to not work here. I did try the model from the paper, but again got significant disagreement between both simulations.

The central question is thus:

*Is it possible that simulating a 3D axisymmetrical problem involving Brownian motion and other forces in a simplified 2D space does not make sense from a physical standpoint in the first place, and so I must run all simulations involving 3D Brownian motion in 3D, even if the problem is axisymmetrical?*

(the original 3D model is from [a 1992 paper by Li and Ahmadi](https://doi.org/10.1080/02786829208959550).)

Comment: How do you add noise into the 2D equations and what numerical method are you using then to simulate the resulting SDEs? Does it work for free particles? Could you be accidentally simulating the Ito versions of the SDE where you meant to look at Stratonovich? The original paper from the very short description of their method seems to be using Ito, but this may not matter in their coordinate system (I didn't look at the equations they were using in any detail).